# Shopify: Iterate and show return button for partial orders on fulfilled items only

Tags: jinja2, shopify, liquid

In Shopify on order.liquid I am trying to add a return button to orders that are only fulfilled. I am having trouble adding this to partial orders that have various fulfillment statuses. Is there a way to access the fulfillment_status on a line item level?

I am able to access values from the order.fulfillment_status but I do not see any values from the line_item.fulfillment_status

```
{%- if order.fulfillment_status == 'partial' -%}
    {% for order in customer.orders %}
        {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
            {%- if line_item.fulfillment_status == 'fulfilled' -%}
                <a class="order-return-button" href="#">Return Item</a>
            {%- endif -%}
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endif -%}
```

I would like the return button to show only for fulfilled items on a line item level for partial orders.

Answer (score 0):

`line_item` does not have property `fulfillment_status`, instead it has `fulfillment`:
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/line_item
https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/fulfillment

Your `if` statement for line item should be more like:
`{% if line_item.fulfillment.item_count == line_item.quantity %}`

So you need something like this:

```
{%- if order.fulfillment_status == 'partial' -%}
    {% for order in customer.orders %}
        {% for line_item in order.line_items %}
            {% if line_item.fulfillment.item_count == line_item.quantity %}
                <a class="order-return-button" href="#">Return Item</a>
            {%- endif -%}
         {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{%- endif -%}
```

give it a shot,

Best of luck

Comment: thank you for this information.
I have a Partial Fulfilled order. 1 item Fulfilled and 1 item unfulfilled.
If I add the Data Attributes in place of the button I get them returned 2 times and both attributes have a qty of 1.
```
<a class="order-return-button" href="#">Line Item Fulfillment Count: {{line_item.fulfillment.item_count}}</a>
            <a class="order-return-button" href="#">Line Item QTY: {{line_item.quantity}}</a>
```
See this image for reference: [https://ibb.co/gF5LXSK](https://ibb.co/gF5LXSK)